# Pra que serve o # (cerquilha) na linguagem Lua?

Tags: lua, operadores, sintaxe

Eu estou assistindo esse [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9G0WyG9vaY) sobre a criação de um jogo e me deparei com algo que não entendi a respeito da linguagem Lua.

Existe um trecho do código onde há a seguinte expressão:

```
ents.objects[#ents.objects]
```

O que o `#` (cerquilha) significa nessa expressão?

Comment: Queres dizer [cerquilha / cardinal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerquilha) :)

Comment: sim. pra que serve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É o operador de comprimento, o *length*. Neste caso está pegando o último elemento do *array* `ents.objects`. Lembre-se que em Lua os *arrays* começam em 1 e não 0. Ele é acessado pelo meta-método `__len`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estou aprendendo `lua` agora. Achei mais simples para escrever jogos (em relação ao `python`). E mais limpo em relação ao PHP. Essa última comparação diga-se que é infeliz

Comment: Eu gosto bastante de Lua mas nunca pude mexer muito.

Answer (score 3):

Usa-se para pegar o tamanho de uma tabela. Lembrando que isso pode não funcionar como esperado pois a table em lua é uma estrutura que, embaixo dos panos, é implementada de forma híbrida que contém uma parte hash table e uma parte array. O # vai pegar o tamanho da parte array, e só é possível ter certeza que vai retornar o tamanho certo quando uma table é utilizada como array, ou seja: **a table tem que ter apenas índices numéricos, começando de 1, sem "buracos" no meio**. Caso contrário, para obter a quantidade de elementos, é preferível iterar e contar.